# How to Serialize XML to a JSON object with Json.NET

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I can serialize XML to a JSON string like this:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<person><name>John</name></person>");
string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString));
```

That would give me:

```
"{\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\"}}"
```

But how can I serialize it to a JSON object? Like this:

```
{"person":{"name":"John"}}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sometimes we just want to make it harder than it is ...

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<person><name>John</name></person>");
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xml));
```

What I did wrong was to serialize the XML into a string and then serialize it again.

Comment: in my case i have a wcf method from which i need to return json string.
Dataset > xml> json
but when i am converting into json string than i am encountering the same problem.
my method signature : 
 [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           UriTemplate = "/methosnamenamespoace?querystring")]
        string mthodname(args);

what should i return in case to get proper json on other end. Please  Guide.

Comment: Can a local .xml file be used in place of the xml string in the Loadxml()?

Comment: @cardiac7 Yes you can use any `XmlDocument` for that. It does not matter how the object was filled with XML.

Answer (score 0):

when you will access data then / automatically does not show . 
I am accessing in HTML5 help of AJAX post . 
Result is showing

in C# result is showing that "{\"person\":{\"name\":\"John\"}}"

But in HTML5 , it is working fine 
{"person":{"name":"John"}}