# Convert XML to D3 JSON

Tags: c#, json, xml, d3.js

Is it possible to convert any XML to below d3.js format. I want to populate my XML into a tree structure. The JSON format has name and corresponding Child nodes. I would like to know if there is any dynamic conversion in C# or any other language.

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to convert `XML` to `json` example and conversely, so if you have a `XML` example that seems very hard to convert to `json`, please give us a link or part of it to convert it to `json` string. As you asking for dynamic conversion method you can convert `XML` to `json` with any programming language you like including `C#`. I'll let you know 2 conversion methods.

1. Read `XML` file and parse it with `C#`
   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c) example will show how to read and parse an `XML` file in `C#`?
   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037085/convert-xml-to-json-using-c-linq) example will show how to Convert `XML` to `JSON` using `LINQ`
2. Dynamic method to conversion
    [This](http://codebeautify.org/jsontoxml) link will help you to convert `XML` to `json` and `json` to `XML` Online.

As you asked I convert your `json` example to `XML` to let you know there is not so much different between `XML` and `json`.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <root>
    <name>flare</name>
     <children>
       <name>analytics</name>
         <children>
        <name>cluster</name>
        <children>
            <name>AgglomerativeCluster</name>
            <size>3938</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>CommunityStructure</name>
            <size>3812</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>HierarchicalCluster</name>
            <size>6714</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>MergeEdge</name>
            <size>743</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>graph</name>
        <children>
            <name>BetweennessCentrality</name>
            <size>3534</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>LinkDistance</name>
            <size>5731</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>MaxFlowMinCut</name>
            <size>7840</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ShortestPaths</name>
            <size>5914</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SpanningTree</name>
            <size>3416</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>optimization</name>
        <children>
            <name>AspectRatioBanker</name>
            <size>7074</size>
        </children>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>animate</name>
    <children>
        <name>Easing</name>
        <size>17010</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>FunctionSequence</name>
        <size>5842</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>interpolate</name>
        <children>
            <name>ArrayInterpolator</name>
            <size>1983</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ColorInterpolator</name>
            <size>2047</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>DateInterpolator</name>
            <size>1375</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Interpolator</name>
            <size>8746</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>MatrixInterpolator</name>
            <size>2202</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>NumberInterpolator</name>
            <size>1382</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ObjectInterpolator</name>
            <size>1629</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>PointInterpolator</name>
            <size>1675</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>RectangleInterpolator</name>
            <size>2042</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>ISchedulable</name>
        <size>1041</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Parallel</name>
        <size>5176</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Pause</name>
        <size>449</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Scheduler</name>
        <size>5593</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Sequence</name>
        <size>5534</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Transition</name>
        <size>9201</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Transitioner</name>
        <size>19975</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>TransitionEvent</name>
        <size>1116</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Tween</name>
        <size>6006</size>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>data</name>
    <children>
        <name>converters</name>
        <children>
            <name>Converters</name>
            <size>721</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>DelimitedTextConverter</name>
            <size>4294</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>GraphMLConverter</name>
            <size>9800</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>IDataConverter</name>
            <size>1314</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>JSONConverter</name>
            <size>2220</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataField</name>
        <size>1759</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataSchema</name>
        <size>2165</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataSet</name>
        <size>586</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataSource</name>
        <size>3331</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataTable</name>
        <size>772</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>DataUtil</name>
        <size>3322</size>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>display</name>
    <children>
        <name>DirtySprite</name>
        <size>8833</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>LineSprite</name>
        <size>1732</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>RectSprite</name>
        <size>3623</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>TextSprite</name>
        <size>10066</size>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>flex</name>
    <children>
        <name>FlareVis</name>
        <size>4116</size>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>util</name>
    <children>
        <name>Arrays</name>
        <size>8258</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Colors</name>
        <size>10001</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Dates</name>
        <size>8217</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Displays</name>
        <size>12555</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Filter</name>
        <size>2324</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Geometry</name>
        <size>10993</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>heap</name>
        <children>
            <name>FibonacciHeap</name>
            <size>9354</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>HeapNode</name>
            <size>1233</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>IEvaluable</name>
        <size>335</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>IPredicate</name>
        <size>383</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>IValueProxy</name>
        <size>874</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>math</name>
        <children>
            <name>DenseMatrix</name>
            <size>3165</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>IMatrix</name>
            <size>2815</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SparseMatrix</name>
            <size>3366</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Maths</name>
        <size>17705</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Orientation</name>
        <size>1486</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>palette</name>
        <children>
            <name>ColorPalette</name>
            <size>6367</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Palette</name>
            <size>1229</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ShapePalette</name>
            <size>2059</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SizePalette</name>
            <size>2291</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Property</name>
        <size>5559</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Shapes</name>
        <size>19118</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Sort</name>
        <size>6887</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Stats</name>
        <size>6557</size>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Strings</name>
        <size>22026</size>
    </children>
</children>
<children>
    <name>vis</name>
    <children>
        <name>axis</name>
        <children>
            <name>Axes</name>
            <size>1302</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Axis</name>
            <size>24593</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>AxisGridLine</name>
            <size>652</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>AxisLabel</name>
            <size>636</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>CartesianAxes</name>
            <size>6703</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>controls</name>
        <children>
            <name>AnchorControl</name>
            <size>2138</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ClickControl</name>
            <size>3824</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Control</name>
            <size>1353</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ControlList</name>
            <size>4665</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>DragControl</name>
            <size>2649</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ExpandControl</name>
            <size>2832</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>HoverControl</name>
            <size>4896</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>IControl</name>
            <size>763</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>PanZoomControl</name>
            <size>5222</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SelectionControl</name>
            <size>7862</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>TooltipControl</name>
            <size>8435</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>data</name>
        <children>
            <name>Data</name>
            <size>20544</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>DataList</name>
            <size>19788</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>DataSprite</name>
            <size>10349</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>EdgeSprite</name>
            <size>3301</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>NodeSprite</name>
            <size>19382</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>render</name>
            <children>
                <name>ArrowType</name>
                <size>698</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>EdgeRenderer</name>
                <size>5569</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>IRenderer</name>
                <size>353</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ShapeRenderer</name>
                <size>2247</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>ScaleBinding</name>
            <size>11275</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Tree</name>
            <size>7147</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>TreeBuilder</name>
            <size>9930</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>events</name>
        <children>
            <name>DataEvent</name>
            <size>2313</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SelectionEvent</name>
            <size>1880</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>TooltipEvent</name>
            <size>1701</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>VisualizationEvent</name>
            <size>1117</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>legend</name>
        <children>
            <name>Legend</name>
            <size>20859</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>LegendItem</name>
            <size>4614</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>LegendRange</name>
            <size>10530</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>operator</name>
        <children>
            <name>distortion</name>
            <children>
                <name>BifocalDistortion</name>
                <size>4461</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>Distortion</name>
                <size>6314</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>FisheyeDistortion</name>
                <size>3444</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>encoder</name>
            <children>
                <name>ColorEncoder</name>
                <size>3179</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>Encoder</name>
                <size>4060</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>PropertyEncoder</name>
                <size>4138</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ShapeEncoder</name>
                <size>1690</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>SizeEncoder</name>
                <size>1830</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>filter</name>
            <children>
                <name>FisheyeTreeFilter</name>
                <size>5219</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>GraphDistanceFilter</name>
                <size>3165</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>VisibilityFilter</name>
                <size>3509</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>IOperator</name>
            <size>1286</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>label</name>
            <children>
                <name>Labeler</name>
                <size>9956</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>RadialLabeler</name>
                <size>3899</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>StackedAreaLabeler</name>
                <size>3202</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>layout</name>
            <children>
                <name>AxisLayout</name>
                <size>6725</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>BundledEdgeRouter</name>
                <size>3727</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>CircleLayout</name>
                <size>9317</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>CirclePackingLayout</name>
                <size>12003</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>DendrogramLayout</name>
                <size>4853</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>ForceDirectedLayout</name>
                <size>8411</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>IcicleTreeLayout</name>
                <size>4864</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>IndentedTreeLayout</name>
                <size>3174</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>Layout</name>
                <size>7881</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>NodeLinkTreeLayout</name>
                <size>12870</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>PieLayout</name>
                <size>2728</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>RadialTreeLayout</name>
                <size>12348</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>RandomLayout</name>
                <size>870</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>StackedAreaLayout</name>
                <size>9121</size>
            </children>
            <children>
                <name>TreeMapLayout</name>
                <size>9191</size>
            </children>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>Operator</name>
            <size>2490</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>OperatorList</name>
            <size>5248</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>OperatorSequence</name>
            <size>4190</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>OperatorSwitch</name>
            <size>2581</size>
        </children>
        <children>
            <name>SortOperator</name>
            <size>2023</size>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children>
        <name>Visualization</name>
        <size>16540</size>
    </children>
    </children>
   </root>
```

It's very simple just need to convert each node to `XML` format, for example:
 Convert `"name": "flare"` to `<name>flare</name>` or `"children"` to `<children>`. I suggest if you have very specific `XML` just make a `C#` model and then serialize it to json like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861708/how-to-serialize-xml-to-a-json-object-with-json-net) example.
I hope this help and solve your problem.

**Edit:** There is not specific json file's format in d3js. D3 is just a library to make data visualization that works with standard json format. just build standard `json` file and use `d3.json()` function to read and parse it.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926539/organization-chart-tree-online-dynamic-collapsible-pictures-in-d3) an example that build [Collapsible Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) with different standard `json` file.